# AJAX: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, ajax, search

I'm beginner in developing.
I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hy4mvRToYQA&ab_channel=Webslesson) which make search function with multiple tags.

here below is my code for search bar:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" id="tags" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <button type="button" name="search" class="btn btn-primary" id="search">>>SEARCH</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <div allign="right">
        <p><b>Total Records - <span id="total_records"></span></b></p>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thread>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>BRAND</th>
                <th>SHOE STYLE</th>
                <th>COLOR</th>
                <th>SHOE IMAGE</th>
                <th>SG SHOE ID</th>
                <th>CUST SHOE ID</th>
                <th>PD TYPE</th>
                <th>SIZE TYPE</th>           
            </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is the code I put for function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();

    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
        url:"fetch_pd_list.php",
        method: "post",
        data:{query:query},
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data){
        //    $('#total_records').text(data.length);
            var html = '';
         
            if ($(data) == null) {data.length = 0};
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].no+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].brand_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].style_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].color_name+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].pd_image+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].sg_code+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].cust_code+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].production_type+'</td>';
                    html += '<td>'+data[count].size_type_name+'</td></tr>'; 
                }
            } else {
                    html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
            } 
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }, 
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        })
    }

$('#search').click(function(){
    var query = $('#tags').val();
    load_data(query);
});

});
</script>
```

and I have this error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

[image]

even if I put some words in search bar, I see there is 'null', not value.

I feel like I missed some important thing such as giving name to the data I want to send...
how can I give a name to the data I want to send?
and how can I connect the named data and function?

many thanks for your kindness in advance:-)

Comment: `$(data) == null` is never `true`. Why are you using the jQuery function here?

Comment: And if it was, you would try to add the `.length` property of `null` to a number

Comment: @SebastianSimon i want to move excel data to database, so want to make search function with multi words so that i can see the data similar excel multi filters, and found that tutorial. thought it is good way to express what i want, but i'm facing this error which i cannot resolve alone..can you share your opinion?

Comment: @Andreas can you explain more detail about this?

Comment: What exactly? If `$(data) == null` would be `true` then `data` would (most likely) be `null` and then you would try to set `null.length = 0` which would also throw an error.